# On the curvature tensor with certain conditions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $(M^{n+m},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $\lbrace X_1,...,X_n,Y_1,...,Y_m\rbrace $ be a locally orthonormal frame for $M$($3\leq n,m$).

If we suppose the curvature tensor $R$ of $g$ satisfies the following conditions, then what can we conclude on $R$ or on $(M,g)$? Or, can we classify $(M,g)$?

$$R(X_i,X_j)X_k=0,\hspace{1cm}i,j,k=1,...,n$$
$$R(Y_i,Y_j)Y_k=0,\hspace{1cm}i,j,k=1,...,m$$
$$R(Y_i,X_j)X_j=f_{ij}Y_i,\hspace{1cm}i=1,...,m,\hspace{1cm}j=1,...,n$$
$$R(X_i,Y_j)Y_j=g_{ij}X_i,\hspace{1cm}i=1,...,n,\hspace{1cm}j=1,...,m$$
$$R(Y_i,X_j)X_k=0,\hspace{1cm} k‎\neq j \hspace{1cm} j,k=1,...,n,\hspace{1cm}i=1,...,m$$
$$R(X_i,Y_j)Y_k=0,\hspace{1cm} k‎\neq j \hspace{1cm} j,k=1,...,m,\hspace{1cm}i=1,...,n$$
where $f_{ij},g_{ij}$ are real functions. All of the indices are constant.

We know that $Spann \lbrace X_1,...,X_n \rbrace $ is invariant under parallel translation.

Comment: Unless you mean to sum on $j$ in your last two equations, these equations are not invariant under $\mathrm{O}(n)\times\mathrm{O}(m)$ frame changes.  Or do you mean these equations to hold for all $\mathrm{O}(n)\times\mathrm{O}(m)$ frame changes (i.e., orthonormal changes of basis in the $X_i$ and orthonormal changes of basis in the $Y_j$)?  Unless one of these is the case, it is unlikely that your system will have a geometric interpretation in terms of the underlying metric and orthogonal splitting of the tangent bundle $TM = \mathbf{X}\oplus\mathbf{Y}$.

Comment: A trivial observation, if we assume that you meant as written, that equations 3 and 4 hold for a fixed $i$ and $j$, with no summation intended:
Take the inner product of the third equation with $Y_i$, and the fourth equation with $X_i$, and swapping the $i$ and $j$ indices, we have that
$$ f = \langle R(Y_i, X_j)X_j, Y_i\rangle = \langle R(X_j,Y_i) Y_i,X_j\rangle = g $$ 
so we must have $f = g$. // When $n = m$ this means that your metric is Einstein.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention. ِ All of indices are constant and every orthonormal frame $\lbrace X_1',...,X_n'\rbrace $ in $Span \lbrace X_1,...,X_n\rbrace $ and  every orthonormal frame $\lbrace Y_1',...,Y_m'\rbrace $ in $Span \lbrace Y_1,...,Y_m\rbrace $ satisfy in the question. Moreover, $n,m$ are not equal.

Comment: In your current version, you have that the Riemann curvature tensor (with all the indices raised) is equal to $$ R = f \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^m (X_i \wedge Y_j) \otimes (X_i\wedge Y_j)$$ A computation using the second Bianchi identities show that this implies $f$ is constant.

Comment: @Solar: Are you sure that the last two sets of equations are the ones you want?  I would have thought that, instead of those, you would have wanted weaker equations of the form $$R(Y_i,X_j)X_k+R(Y_i,X_k)X_j =2 \delta_{jk}f\,Y_i$$ and $$R(X_i,Y_j)Y_k+R(X_i,Y_k)Y_j =2 \delta_{jk}g\,X_i\,.$$

Comment: @RobertBryant The equations in this post are a continuation of [my previous post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232283/on-eigenspace-of-a-bundle-map-which-is-the-horizontal-part-of-a-complex-structur). Also it is worth mentioning that these equations are derived from the integrability  of $\bar{J}$ and the existence of such $a+b$ vector fields in that question.